# log statement avoid computing parameters

Tags: c#

In c# is there a way to avoid computing expensive parameters.

Example

```
DebugLog(object.getName());
```

If I want to avoid the call to getName(say its expensive) I have to do

```
#if DEBUG
DebugLog(object.getName());
#endif
```

In other languages I can make a log macro that is a no-op if the log level is a certain way and just do

```
DebugLog(anything i want as it just is skipped)
```

Is there some way other then to have ugly defines around every single log?

Comment: Do you have access to the `DebugLog` method? Mark it with the   `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2248025/607701. The correct answer is to use lambda expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In can be done with help of conditional attributes. E.g. if you have `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]`, and `DEBUG` is not defined, the entire function call, including evaluation of parameters is skipped.

This is, for instance, how [`Debug.Assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx) works.

For instance, this code

```
static void Main()
{
    Log(F());
}

[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]
static void Log(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

static string F()
{
    Console.WriteLine("foo");
    return "bar";
}
```

outputs

```
foo
bar
```

in Debug configuration, where `DEBUG` is defined, and nothing in Release configuration.

Comment: +1. Your answer would be much more helpful if you provided an example.

Comment: @DavidPeden The answer you refer to does run-time checking. PO mentioned `#if DEBUG`, so I guess compile-time checking is quite OK here.

Comment: @AlexD The final question "Is there some way other then to have ugly defines around every single log?" clearly demonstrates a desire to avoid #defs. Most mature logging frameworks support lambda expressions which do not require an explicit run-time check.